# Including javascripts not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a little javascript snippet for including javascripts only if they was not included before.

That is working with my own scripts, but with two third-party libraries it's not working and I really don't know why.

```
    var included_files = new Array();
    function include_once(script_filename) {
        if (!in_array(script_filename, included_files)) {
            included_files[included_files.length] = script_filename;
            include_dom(script_filename);
        }
    }
    function in_array(needle, haystack) {
        for (var i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++) {
            if (haystack[i] == needle) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    function include_dom(script_filename) {
        var html_doc = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
        var js = document.createElement('script');
        js.setAttribute('language', 'javascript');
        js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        js.setAttribute('src', script_filename);
        html_doc.appendChild(js);
        return false;
    }

function loaded() {
    include_once("shared/scripts/jquery.min.js");
    include_once("shared/scripts/iscroll.js");

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
}
```

error: $ is not defined.
If I import jQuery the regular way its working and it says "iScroll" is not defined (because I'm using it later).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did someone say callback?

```
function include_once(script_filename, callback) {
        if (!in_array(script_filename, included_files)) {
            included_files[included_files.length] = script_filename;
            include_dom(script_filename, callback);
        }
    }

function include_dom(script_filename, callback) {
    var html_doc = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
    var js = document.createElement('script');
    js.setAttribute('language', 'javascript');
    js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    js.setAttribute('src', script_filename);
    if(callback && callback != 'undefined'){
        js.onload =  callback;
        js.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 'complete') callback();
        }
    }
    html_doc.appendChild(js);
    return false;
}

function loaded() {
    include_once("shared/scripts/jquery.min.js", function(){
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("hello");
        });
    });
    include_once("shared/scripts/iscroll.js");
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much!
script has to be replaced by "js" but everything works fine.

Answer (score 7):

`include_dom` is asynchronous. It loads the scripts in parallel, and you can't really determine when the scripts will be loaded. You try to use jQuery right after you started the download, which doesn't work.

You need to use a script that allows you to specify a callback for loaded scripts. I would recommend require.js

Comment: How do you see that it is asynchronous?
Can I change the method so that it's not?

Answer (score 4):

You are adding the scripts to the DOM, but not letting them load before you try to use the functions they provide.

You need to bind a callback to the load event of the script elements you are adding.

(At least in most browsers, you might have to implement some hacks in others; you may wish to examine the source code for jQuery's getScript method).

Answer (score 2):

Use a script loader. [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) will do everything you are trying to do and more